# How can I write the disk-image of a Linux computer with the "dd" command to another computer connected with a LAN cable?

Tags: linux, disk-image

I have a computer with Linux (A) and another computer with a formatted hard disk(B).  If I connect two computers with LAN cable, how can I write the disk-image of computer A to computer B using the *dd* command?

Comment: You might be able to use the NBD (network block device) protocol to do this.  I hope you need like 10,000 of them because this is FAR more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: Copying the image of a disk drive with active (i.e. mounted) filesystem(s) is a bad idea.  Why do you mention that the destination drive is formatted?  Do you intend to replace that filesystem, or write the image as a file?

Comment: @sawdust I want to clone it to another computer as practical as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
# destination machine:
nc -l -p 19000 | bzip2 -d | dd bs=16M of=/dev/sda
# source machine:
dd bs=16M if=/dev/sda | bzip2 -c | nc 192.168.100.2 19000
```

[source](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-clone-linux-disk-partition-over-network-using-dd/)

You may not want to use bzip2 though